# Send mails in bulk rather than sending each mail immediately upon completion

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I've a loop to send about 75 emails, each with an individual attachment for each individual recipient. This works, but I'm wondering how to create all these, and send them all in one go, instead of feeding them through one at a time.

I know I can use `.display` instead of `.send` to have the email show in Outlook, but is there any way to use VBA to temporarily disable sending emails, and then enable it once all mails are created?

My code looks something like this -

```
Dim employee_name As Variant
Dim file_path As String
Dim file_ext As String
Dim AGENT_FILE As String
Dim e As Variant
Dim email As Variant
Dim a As Integer

a = "0"
Sheets("EMAILS").Select
employee_name = Range("A1:A76").Value

file_path = "H:\Email TEST\"
file_ext = ".xlsx"

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim distributionList As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each e In employee_name

    If e <> "" Then 

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With Sheets("EMAILS").Select
            a = a + 1
            email = Range("B" & a).Value
            AGENT_FILE = file_path & e & file_ext

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = email
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Daily Stats"
                .Body = "Hello ," & vbCrLf & _
                  vbCrLf & _
                  "Attached are your daily stats." & vbCrLf & _
                  vbCrLf & _
                  "Regards, " & vbCrLf & _
                  "Oliver Lockett"
                .Attachments.Add AGENT_FILE
                .send
            End With
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing

    End If

Next

Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: You could always `sendat=now ... .DeferredDeliveryTime=dateAdd("s", 30, sendat)` which will hold them in the oubox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? Send is asynchronous, it will not block your code.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't block it, but outlook sending one after another starts to eat up system resources and slows everything down. I'd rather run the code, and then have them send all at once. Its go to be possible

Comment: Unless you have a very slow machine on a very fast network, the performance hit caused by the Outlook spooler asynchronously sending messages one at a time will be negligible compared to the execution of your code. Have you actually profiled your code when you call MailItem.Save vs MailItem.Send?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar kind of stuff years ago...

I preferred using .save instead of .send. Because of this all emails where saved under drafts....once all Emails are saved....I had a macro in Outlook to send all drafts...
This can be acheived here

http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-309127/send-all-mails-from-my-drafts-folder-at-one-go-in-outlook-2003

Comment: Yeah .send is blocked in my environment, .save works very well.  Then when you open outlook, all your saved drafts can be sent.